# Opening an existing IndexedDB from a different page/script?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

On my list page, I have successfully created a new indexedDB instance  as follows:

**`settings.js`**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if (!($('#route_instance'))) {
        //do nothing
    } else {
        saveRoomListOffline();
    }

    $('#all_routes li a').click(function(){
        $.jStorage.set('currentRoute', $(this).attr('rel'), { TTL: 28800000 }); 
    });
});


function saveRoomListOffline() {
    var rooms_array = [];
    $('#route_instance li').each(function () {
        var roomId = parseInt($(this).attr('id'), 10);
        var seqNo = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'), 10);
        var roomlink = $(this).find('a');
        var roomName = $(roomlink).html();
        var routeNumber = parseInt($('#rn').html());
        room_as_dict = {
            'room_id': roomId,
            'room_seq': seqNo,
            'room_name': roomName,
            'route_number' : routeNumber
        }
        rooms_array.push(room_as_dict);
    });

    //create idb
    var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;

    openRequest = window.indexedDB.open("rooms", 1);
    // Create the schema
    openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function() {
        var db = openRequest.result;
        var itemStore = db.createObjectStore("rooms", {keyPath: "room_id"});
        var index = itemStore.createIndex("RoomIndex", ["route_number", "room_seq"]);
    };

    openRequest.onerror = function(event) {
        console.error(event);
    };

    openRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
        var db = openRequest.result;
        db.onerror = function(event) {
            // Generic error handler for all errors targeted at this database's requests
            console.error(event.target);
            window.alert("Database error: " + event.target.wePutrrorMessage || event.target.error.name || event.target.error || event.target.errorCode);
        };
        var transaction = db.transaction('rooms', "readwrite");
        var itemStore = transaction.objectStore("rooms");
        var index = itemStore.index("RoomIndex", ["route_number", "room_seq"]);
        putNext(rooms_array, itemStore);

        // Close the db when the transaction is done
        transaction.oncomplete = function() {
            db.close();
        };
    };
}

function putNext(rooms_array, itemStore) {
    for (i = 0; i < rooms_array.length; i++) { 
        itemStore.put(rooms_array[i]);
    } 
}
```

On the next page, `index.html`, I want to retrieve the data stored with the above script, but it is not working:

**`static-settings.js`**

```
function getRoomsInRoute() {
    var routeNumber = $.jStorage.get('currentRoute', '');
    // access all possible browser names for iDB
    var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;
    var db = indexedDB.open('rooms', 1);
    var transaction = db.transaction([ 'rooms' ], 'readwrite');
    var store = transaction.objectStore('rooms');
    var index = store.index('route_number');
    var range = IDBKeyRange.only(routeNumber);
    var request = index.openCursor(range);
    request.onsuccess = function() {
    var cursor = this.result;
    if(cursor) {
        var room = cursor.value;
        $('#mylist').append("<li id="+ JSON.stringify(room.room_id) +" rel="+ JSON.stringify(room.room_seq) +"> " + JSON.stringify(room.room_name) + "</li> ");
        cursor.continue();
    } else {
        console.log('No rooms found or all rooms iterated');
    }
  };
  request.onblocked = function(event) {
        console.log("Error, cannot open database. Error message: Database in blocked state. " +
                "Please close all open windows, clear browser cache and use a fresh window.");
    };

    //Callback for error upon DB open
    request.onerror = function(event) {
      console.log('Error, cannot open database');
    };

    //Callback for success upon DB open
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        console.log('Success. ');
    };

    //Callback for onupgradeneeded upon DB open
    request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        console.log('onupgradeneeded. Create/modify the database schema');
        this.dbHandler = e.target.result;
        this.dbHandler.createTable('rooms', {keyPath: 'room_id'});
    };
}
```

**`index.html`**

```
<script src="/js/lib/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- load the json2 library (required for jstorage use) -->
<script src="/js/lib/json2.js"></script>
<!-- load the jstorage library *-->
<script src="/js/lib/jstorage.js"></script>
<script src="/js/static-settings.js"></script>
```

**list page** - same as `index.html` except:

```
<script src="js/settings.js"></script>
```

The error message I am getting is:

**Update**. New error message (I have removed Dexie and done the whole thing in IndexedDB):

> Uncaught TypeError: db.transaction is not a function at
>   getRoomsInRoute (static-settings.js:390) at HTMLDocument.
>   (static-settings.js:29)
>
> at j (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2)
>
> at k (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2)

Comment: Please list the included scripts for each page (e.g. the script tags from html) or explain how else you are loading scripts and show how the variable `$.jStorage` is assigned a value.

Comment: Added script tags; the jStorage value is set on line 10 of the `settings.js` snippet above.

Comment: OK, so my worry is that with the line `var db = new Dexie("roomslist", {keyPath: 'room_id'});` in *static-settings.js*, that I have created a new db instance

Comment: The error message means that $.jStorage is undefined. Try placing the statement `console.log('Is jstorage a defined object?', $.jStorage);` before the call to `$.jStorage.get` and examining its output.

Comment: If it is undefined, then you may be not including it, or you may be calling it before it is loaded. Try waiting for the script to load. One way to wait is to only call getRoomsInRoute after DOMContentLoaded event fired.

Comment: Thanks. I did as you suggested and jStorage does exist. This was the response: `Is jstorage a defined object? {version: "0.4.12", set: ƒ, get: ƒ, deleteKey: ƒ, setTTL: ƒ, …}`

Comment: If it exists then you should not be getting the same error message. Can you confirm you are getting a different error message now?

Comment: yes, it's a different error message now - sorry for creating confusion

Comment: I have also stripped out the Dexie completely and created the database using plain indexeddb code (rewritten post, inserted new code, and updated error message accordingly)

Comment: The statement `var db = indexedDB.open` does not work that way. `indexedDB.open` returns an IDBOpenRequest. You have to wait for the success event of the request to fire, and then get db from request.result.

Comment: I just got the database to open and run through my query, I am now trying to restrict the query by range. After that I will post my code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a lot of help from the MozDev documentation: [IDBCursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor) and [IDBKeyRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBKeyRange)**:**

**`settings.js`**

```
function saveRoomListOffline() {
    var rooms_array = [];
    $('#route_instance li').each(function () {
        var roomId = parseInt($(this).attr('id'), 10);
        var seqNo = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'), 10);
        var roomlink = $(this).find('a');
        var roomName = $(roomlink).html();
        var routeNumber = parseInt($('#rn').html());
        room_as_dict = {
            'room_id': roomId,
            'room_seq': seqNo,
            'room_name': roomName,
            'route_number' : routeNumber
        }
        rooms_array.push(room_as_dict);
    });

    //create idb
    var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;

    openRequest = window.indexedDB.open("rooms", 1);
    // Create the schema
    openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function() {
        var db = openRequest.result;
        var itemStore = db.createObjectStore("rooms", {keyPath: "room_id"});
        var index = itemStore.createIndex("RoomIndex", ["route_number"]);
    };

    openRequest.onerror = function(event) {
        console.error(event);
    };

    openRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
        var db = openRequest.result;
        db.onerror = function(event) {
            // Generic error handler for all errors targeted at this database's requests
            console.error(event.target);
            window.alert("Database error: " + event.target.error.name || event.target.error || event.target.errorCode);
        };
        var transaction = db.transaction('rooms', "readwrite");
        var itemStore = transaction.objectStore("rooms");
        var index = itemStore.index("RoomIndex", ["route_number"]);
        putNext(rooms_array, itemStore);

        // Close the db when the transaction is done
        transaction.oncomplete = function() {
            db.close();
        };
    };
}
```

**`static-settings.js`**

```
function getRoomsInRoute() {
    var routeNumber = $.jStorage.get('currentRoute', '');
    var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;

    openRequest = window.indexedDB.open("rooms", 1);
    openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function() {
        var db = openRequest.result;
        var itemStore = db.createObjectStore("rooms", {keyPath: "room_id"});
        var index = itemStore.createIndex("RoomIndex", ["route_number"]);
    };

    openRequest.onerror = function(event) {
        console.error(event);
    };

    openRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
        var db = openRequest.result;
        db.onerror = function(event) {
            // Generic error handler for all errors targeted at this database's requests
            console.error(event.target);
            console.log("Database error: " + event.target.error.name || event.target.error || event.target.errorCode);
        };
        var transaction = db.transaction(['rooms'], "readwrite");
        var itemStore = transaction.objectStore("rooms");
        var index = itemStore.index("RoomIndex", ["route_number"]);
        console.log('DB opened');

    var intRouteNumber = parseInt(routeNumber);

    itemStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;
        if(cursor) {
            if(cursor.value.route_number == routeNumber) {
                $('#mylist').append("<li id="+ cursor.value.room_id +" rel="+ cursor.value.room_seq +"> " + '<small>'+ cursor.value.room_seq + '&nbsp;</small>' + cursor.value.room_name + "</li> ");
            }

            cursor.continue();
        } else {
            console.log('Entries all displayed.');
        }
    };

        // Close the db when the transaction is done
        transaction.oncomplete = function() {
            db.close();
        };
    };
}
```